# Segmentation fault involving pointer to the same object type

Tags: c++, oop, segmentation-fault

I have the following minimal version of my code (I have set all data fields to public for debugging purposes):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using std::cout; using std::vector; using std::string;

class Population;  // forward declaration

class Person {
    public:
        Person *spouse;
        void marry(Population &p, int i);  // defined after Population class
};

class Population {
    public:
        vector<Person> people;
        void add(Person p) {
            people.push_back(p);
        }
};

void Person::marry(Population &p, int i) {
    *spouse = p.people.at(i);
}

int main() {
    Person john; Person jane;

    Population pop;
    pop.add(john); pop.add(jane);

    john.marry(pop, 1);  // tries to marries Jane, but seg fault
}
```

It compiles fine, but it gives a segmentation fault during runtime because of the following line:

```
*spouse = p.people.at(i);
```

What exactly is giving this seg fault, and how can I get around it?

Comment: Don’t dereference a null ptr

Comment: @Taekahn could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: `Person *spouse` is never set to point to anything, so (unless there is some other unposted code that sets it to point to a valid `Person` object), trying to dereference that uninitialized pointer will invoke undefined behavior (and likely cause a crash)

Comment: There looks like there are several oddities (*bad assumptions about how C++ works*) in this program.  Note that "compiling fine" is a low bar, and does not necessarily mean the program is correct.

Comment: @Eljay If you don't mind, could you list those oddities? I have already taken care of my pointer issue, and it would be great if I could further learn from your observations.

Comment: There are many fundamental problems with the shown code. Let's start with the second obvious problem, after the reason for the segfault: even though `john` here allegedly has been married, the completely different "john" in the `pop` is still very much a bachelor.

Comment: There are some weird things going on given your class design and what you're intending to do here: There are 2 johns and 2 janes by the point you call `marry`; one of each can spontaneously die and be replaced by clones, if the population grows. This makes it impossible to keep their addresses stable. For that to work you necessarily need stable addresses of people which could e.g. be achieved by using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Person>>` this would then allow you to marry 2 people without running the risk of the addresses changing when changing the population size.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik @fabian  Thank you for pointing that out. Wouldn't changing to `void add (Person &p)` also fix this problem?

Comment: No, it would not. Every object in C++ is different. Your `std::vector` contains objects. These objects are different from any other objects in the program. Adding something to the vector, no matter how it is done, whether via a reference, a pointer, or two pointers, etc., in the end will make a copy of the object in order to place it in a vector. Additionally, the vector will make copies of objects it already contains as part of growing the vector's size. Any attempt to point to objects that exist in a vector will always end in tears.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for the insight. Do you have recommendations of how I could improve this class design, where the 2 classes are so intertwined?

Comment: The "minimal version" of the shown code makes it somewhat unclear how all of these objects are supposed to work, and relate with each other. The overall class design depends very closely on what these classes are supposed to do, and what kinds of things must happen to them. These low-level details will control the overall class design.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "even though john here allegedly has been married, the completely different "john" in the pop is still very much a bachelor. " - this one time where concept of "relation between data structures" becomes literal.

Answer (score 1):

```
*spouse = p.people.at(i);
```

This line of code does the following, in C++: 1) Return a reference to the `i`th object in the `p.people` vector, and 2) copy the referenced object to another object that this `spouse` pointer is pointing to.

> What exactly is giving this seg fault

Well, a necessary requirement for copying one object, into another object that a pointer is pointing to, is that the pointer, `spouse`, must be a pointer to a valid, ***existing*** object.

There's nothing in the shown code that initializes the `spouse` pointer to point to some existing object. This is most certainly the reason for your program's crash.

> and how can I get around it?

The `spouse` pointer must be initialized to point to a valid object. However there are several defects in these objects' overall design, as discussed in the comments, so you will likely need to completely redesign your objects' entire hierarchy, and how the various objects relate with each other.

Comment: Nice answer!  We posted in the same minute :-)

Answer (score 0):

### What's the problem?

The problem is that the following statement does not do what you think it does:

```
*spouse = p.people.at(i);
```

This statement takes an unitialized pointer `spouse`, and tries to assign the `Person` it points to (but it doesn't point to anything valid) by copying the content of `p.people.at(i)`.

Since the `spouse` pointer is not initialized, this is UB (undefined behavior) and the segfault is one of the many possible symptoms.

### How to solve it?

What you probably wanted to do is to assign to the `spouse` pointer the address of the spouse person:

```
spouse = &p.people.at(i);
```

This would work better in the case of your small snippet. But it would not be a reliable solution:  if you'd add new people to the population vector, the vector could grow, and in some cases the vector content could be moved to a different place, thus making all the previously obtained pointers to its element invalid (and again,  UB if you'd try to access them).

You could instead consider keeping the spouse as an index, or manage the persons in the population in a way that preserves their address, for example creating the persons in a map, or make the vector a vector of addresses to persons that would be copy-created when you do the `add()`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

The whole class design needs a bit of ajustment. Otherwise a person can be copied resulting in confusion about who a person is married to.

Given the fact that you want to represent marriage by storing a pointer to the partner means you've got some requirements:

- If the data about a person gets stored in a different memory location, the spouse needs to be informed
- Any move of the memory location should leave only one person valid; otherwise you wouldn't be sure, if the spouse pointer of the spouse points to the intended person.

A solution this problem is implementing move semantics for `Person`.

```
class Person {
public:
    Person() = default; // default constructor required by vector; also used for creating unmarried people

    ~Person()
    {
         if (spouse != nullptr)
         {
             // spouse now can no longer access their spouse
             spouse->spouse = nullptr;
         }
    }

    Person(Person&& old)
        : spouse(old.spouse)
    {
        if (spouse != nullptr)
        {
            spouse->spouse = this; // tell spouse the new address of the partner
            old.spouse = nullptr; // prevent destructor of old objects from doing incorrect updates to the spouse
        }
    }

    Person& operator=(Person&& old)
    {
        if (spouse != nullptr)
        {
            spouse->spouse = nullptr;
        }
        spouse = old.spouse;
        if (spouse != nullptr)
        {
            spouse->spouse = this; // tell spouse the new address of the partner
            old.spouse = nullptr; // prevent destructor of old objects from doing incorrect updates to the spouse
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void marry(Person& newSpouse)
    {
        if (spouse != nullptr)
        {
            // still married, so throw an exception or divorce; I'll choose divorce here
            spouse->spouse = nullptr;
        }
        spouse = &newSpouse;
        spouse->spouse = this;
    }

    Person* GetSpouse()
    {
        return spouse;
    }

private:
    // spouse data managed internally; don't provide write access outsize of this class
    Person *spouse {nullptr};

};
```

Now `std::vector<Person>` will automatically do updates on a resize of the backing storage, since it uses the move semantics...

```
std::vector<Person> population;
population.emplace_back();
population.emplace_back();

// note: the reference may be invalidated on a vector resize
auto& john = population[0];
auto& jane = population[1];

john.marry(jane);
```